# Shorter way to check for not null for multiple variables

Tags: java

I have three `Integer` variables, where I am not allowed to change to primitive `int` and I need to check if at least one of them have a value greater than 0. Is there a shorter / cleaner way to rewrite my code below:

```
Integer foo = // null or some value
Integer bar = // null or some value
Integer baz = // null or some value

boolean atLeastOnePositive = (foo != null && foo > 0) || (bar != null && bar > 0) || (baz != null && baz > 0)

return atLeastOnePositive;
```

Comment: I guess that introducing a `isPositive` method is a bit of an overkill in your situation?

Comment: So you do expect those to be null occasionally?

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller Maybe too much but still probably more reader-friendly than what I have so far.

Comment: @Amadán Yes. I will get the values from a method call getFoo() get Bar() .. which might return null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *don't* want to introduce a new method with a generic solution to the problem, your way is perfectly fine and I don't see much room for improvement.

If you *do* want to introduce a new method, I'd suggest to combine the solutions of maio290 and Iczapski. When using a stream, filters enhance readability:

```
public static boolean containsAtleastOnePositive(final Integer... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .anyMatch(v -> v > 0);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, `final` is redundant here, no?

Comment: I like your approach. Thank you.

Comment: @user7294900 I like to declare parameters as final to protect myself from accidentally changing them in the method. This wouldn't affect the caller but I'd work with a wrong reference then.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Stream` and do like this:

```
boolean atLeastOnePositive = Stream.of(foo, bar, baz)
  .anyMatch(value -> value != null && value > 0);
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with streams yet. It's probably time to change that.Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I guess a varargs method would be the cleanest way:

```
public static boolean atLeastOnePositive(Integer...integers)
{
    for(Integer integer : integers)
    {
        if(integer != null && integer > 0) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Had something similar with an array as parameter. But your approach with varargs is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method below to return true if var is positive and false if var is negative or null.

```
public boolean isPositive(Integer var) {
        return (0 < (var == null ? 0 : var));
}
```

Comment: You should rename the method though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for multiple arguments this will become unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `Optional<Integer>` instead of nullable `Integer` variable:

```
final Optional<Integer> foo = Optional.of(-1);
final Optional<Integer> bar = Optional.of(2);
final Optional<Integer> baz = Optional.empty();
final boolean atLeastOnePositive = Stream.of(foo, bar, baz)
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .anyMatch(x -> x > 0);
```